# Unable to find Entity not found exception when using one-to-many bidirectional

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

When ever post the data using postman or run the program , facing below error:

> Unable to find com.example.entity.Product with id 1; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.example.entity.Product with id 1

Below is parent class:

```java
@Entity
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer cust_Id;
    private String cust_name;
    private String city;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer")
    private List<Product> products;
}

Child class:
@Entity
public class Product {
    @Id
    private Integer pid;
    private String pname;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_cust_id")
    private Customer customer;
}
```

Comment: What hibernate version do you use?

Comment: Spring boot with data-jpa, Spring boot-2.0.1.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

`@NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)` results in EAGER loading for `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` field. [Refer here](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-3917?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel&showAll=true)